# Python TypeError while using xml.etree.ElemenTree and requests

Tags: python, xml, urllib2, python-requests

This works for me:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'http://example.com'
# this url points to a `xml` page
tree = ET.parse(urlopen(url))
```

However, when I switch to `requests`, something was wrong:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
url = 'http://example.com'
# this url points to a `xml` page
tree = ET.parse(requests.get(url))
```

The trackback error is showed below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 tree = ET.parse(requests.get(url, proxies={'http': '192.168.235.36:7788'}))

/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in parse(source, parser)
   1180 def parse(source, parser=None):
   1181     tree = ElementTree()
-> 1182     tree.parse(source, parser)
   1183     return tree
   1184 

/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in parse(self, source, parser)
    645         close_source = False
    646         if not hasattr(source, "read"):
--> 647             source = open(source, "rb")
    648             close_source = True
    649         try:

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Response found
```

So, my question is: wha is wrong with `requests` in my situation and how can I make it work `ET` with `requests`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the `requests` *respones object* to ElementTree; you want to pass in the [raw file object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content) instead:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
ET.parse(r.raw)
```

`.raw` returns the 'file-like' socket object, from which `ElementTree.parse()` will read, just like it'll read from the `urllib2` response (which is itself a file-like object).

Concrete example:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.enetpulse.com/wp-content/uploads/sample_xml_feed_enetpulse_soccer.xml', stream=True)
>>> tree = ET.parse(r.raw)
>>> tree
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree object at 0x109dadc50>
>>> tree.getroot().tag
'spocosy'
```

If you have a compressed URL, the raw socket (like `urllib2`) returns the compressed data undecoded; in that case you can use the `ET.fromstring()` method on the [binary response content](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content):

```
r = requests.get(url)
ET.fromstring(r.content)
```

Comment: I have tries this before, but not worked. I got this back: `ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
`

Comment: My apologies, the current API requires that you use `stream=True` for the raw reads to work properly, otherwise the data is downloaded early. Try again with the updated answer.

Comment: This doesn't work as is, as `requests` has already read data coming from the socket at the end of the first line. Passing `stream=True` as argument to the request is mandatory

Comment: @doukremt: that is what I am saying in my comments. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters It works! You have always been very helpful to me. Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

You're not feeding ElementTree the response text, but the `requests` `Response` object itself, which is why you get the type error: `need string or buffer, Response found`. Do this instead:

```
r = requests.get(url)
tree = ET.fromstring(r.text)
```

Comment: This won't work for two reasons: `r.text` is the Unicode (decoded) result, you should always parse XML as un-decoded data, and `ET.parse()` wants a filename or file-like object. `ET.parse()` will see the `r.text` result as a filename and pass it to `open()`.