# XML Parsing with ElementTree and Requests

Tags: xml, python-3.x, python-requests, elementtree

I am trying to work with the Yahoo Weather API, but I am having a few issues parsing the `XML` that the API responds with. I am using `Python 3.4`. Here's the code I am working with:

```
weather_url = 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=%s&u=%s'
url = weather_url % (zip_code, units)

try:
    rss = parse(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw).getroot()

    conditions = rss.find('channel/item/{%s}condition' % weather_ns)

    return {
        'current_condition': conditions.get('text'),
        'current_temp': conditions.get('temp'),
        'title': rss.findtext('channel/title')
    }
except:
    raise
```

---

Here's the stack trace that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jonathan/PycharmProjects/pyweather/pyweather/pyweather.py", line 42, in yahoo_conditions
    rss = parse(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw).getroot()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1187, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

---

The xml.etree.ElementTree parse function doesn't like the raw object returned by the requests library. Looking into it a little bit deeper, the raw object resolves to

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265', stream=True)
>>> r.raw
<requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f32c24f9e48>
```

I referenced [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16933729), but it's still leading to the same issue. Why doesn't the approach above work? Is the urllib3 response object not supported with the ElementTree.parse function? I have read all of the docs, but they haven't enlightened me at all.

The doc list is here:

- [xml.etree.ElementTree.parse doc](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse)
- [requests.Request doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Request)
- [urllib3.response.HTTPResponse doc](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#urllib3.response.HTTPResponse)

**Edit:**
After more experimentation, I still haven't found a solution to the problem outlined above. However, I have found a workaround. If you use the ElementTree's *fromstring* method on the XML content, everything works fine.

```
def fetch_xml(url):
    """
    Fetch a url and parse the document's XML.

    :param url: the URL that the XML is located at.
    :return: the root element of the XML.
    :raises:
        :requests.exceptions.RequestException: Requests could not open the URL.
        :xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: xml.etree.ElementTree failed to parse the XML document.
    """

    return ET.fromstring(requests.get(url).content)
```

I guess the downside to this approach is that it uses more memory. What do you think? I'd like to get the communities opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the ElementTree's *fromstring* method on the XML content, everything works fine.

```
def fetch_xml(url):
    """
    Fetch a url and parse the document's XML.

    :param url: the URL that the XML is located at.
    :return: the root element of the XML.
    :raises:
        :requests.exceptions.RequestException: Requests could not open the URL.
        :xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: xml.etree.ElementTree failed to parse the XML document.
    """

    return ET.fromstring(requests.get(url).content)
```

I guess the downside to this approach is that it uses more memory.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using streaming with requests to download some RSS XML data? Do you want to keep a connection open all the time? Weather hardly changes that quickly, so why not just poll the service every 5 minutes instead?

Below is the complete code for doing a poll and parsing using BeautifulSoup and requests. Short and sweet.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=%s&u=%s' % (2459115, "c"))
if r.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    print("Current condition: ", soup.find("description").string)
    print("Temperature: ", soup.find('yweather:condition')['temp'])
    print("Title: ", soup.find("title").string)
else:
    r.raise_for_status()
```

Output:

```
Current condition:  Yahoo! Weather for New York, NY
Temperature:  28
Title:  Yahoo! Weather - New York, NY
```

There is a lot more you can do with Beautifulsoup. Look up its excellent documentation.

Comment: I had the 'stream=True' on because the API requires it to get the raw data. See the docs [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raw). My second solution is more elegant and fully functional. Thanks for the suggested libraries though, I will have to take a look!